# How to get the metadata from a Markdown file using python-markdown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown

I am trying to use [`python-markdown`](https://python-markdown.github.io/) to extract metadata from the following file:

```
---
title: this is the title and it is compulsory
tags: this part is optional
something: this is not interesting, only 'title' and 'tags' is
---
some content
```

The [documentation](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/meta_data/) for metadata gives two examples:

```
markdown.markdown(some_text, extensions=['meta'])
```

and

```
>>> md = markdown.Markdown(extensions = ['meta'])
>>> html = md.convert(text)
>>> # Meta-data has been stripped from output
>>> print html
<p>This is the first paragraph of the document.</p>

>>> # View meta-data
>>> print md.Meta
{
'title' : ['My Document'],
'summary' : ['A brief description of my document.'],
'authors' : ['Waylan Limberg', 'John Doe'],
'date' : ['October 2, 2007'],
'blank-value' : [''],
'base_url' : ['http://example.com']
}
```

I cannot make out from these examples how to **actually** get the metadata:

- the first example returns an `str`, which of course does not have the `Meta` property
- the second example does not load `text`, except for `html` (which is not used to extract the metadata).

Answer (score 5):

I found it: `md.convert()` works **inplace** (in other words, modifies `md`).

The code

```
data = pathlib.Path(note).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['meta'])
md.convert(data)
print(md.Meta)
```

will correctly output the metadata from the file `note`